# How to reverse selection sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I'm trying to write this selection sort from high to low and I'm not quite sure how to do that. I'm pretty new to sorting algorithms.

```
public  void selectionSort(String[ ] data){
    // for each position, from 0 up, find the next smallest item 
    // and swap it into place
    for (int place=0; place<data.length-1; place++){
        int minIndex = place;
        for (int sweep=place+1; sweep<data.length; sweep++){
            if (data[sweep].compareTo(data[minIndex]) < 0)
                minIndex=sweep;
        }
        swap(data, place, minIndex);
    }
}
```

The reason to why I'm trying to change it is that the selection sort here runs through the remaining part of the array, looking for the minimum value and then swaps it to the front.I want to change the algorithm so that it also looks for the maximum value in the remaining part, and swaps it to the back, so that it builds up a sorted list from the front and the back at the same time.

All help would be appreciated :)

Comment: what do you mean? descending order?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi yeah, descending order

Comment: I believe only change - `if (data[sweep].compareTo(data[minIndex]) > 0)`

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder so its doesnt have something to do with the for loop?

Comment: yes it is, comparison is the key of the sort.

Comment: Descending order is the same as ascending order except you swap the sign. or swap the comparison instead of `a.compateTo(b) > 0` you can do `b.compareTo(a) > 0` or `a.compareTo(b) < 0` or `-a.compareTo(b) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to negate the `compareTo` method

```
if(data[sweep].compareTo(data[minIndex]) > 0)
    minIndex=sweep;
```

Comment: so Its not something to do with the forloops?

Comment: No, everything remains the same, but instead of greater than you use less than

Comment: so the problem I'm trying to asnwer here is that the standard algorithm runs through the remaining part of the array, looking for the minimum value and then swaps it to the front. Change the algorithm so that it also looks for the maximum value in the remaining part, and swaps it to the back, so that it builds up a sorted list from the front and the back at the same time. Does this method do this? @SleimanJneidi

Answer (score 2):

A select sort find the smallest remaining item in each iteration and puts in the right place. Instead, you want to find the **largest** remaining item. The simplest way of doing this is by just flipping the selection condition. Instead of:

```
if (data[sweep].compareTo(data[minIndex]) < 0)
```

You should use:

```
if (data[sweep].compareTo(data[minIndex]) > 0)
```

Comment: Oh okay, I tried it and I think it works. Does it make it slower sorting an unordered set than when its ascending?

Comment: I have a method which checks if array is ordered, and it says that it isn't? I'm really confused

Comment: @NandaArdianto let's keep it to one question per post. Please have a new post with that method's code?